# Flutter error building for iOS "ld: framework not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

I've been working for a few weeks on a Flutter app which I run on Android and iOS. It worked well until some days ago I upgraded the flutter version and some package dependencies, and it suddenly stopped building for iOS.
There have been multiple issues I have managed to solve, but I can figure out this one. Now, each time I try to build the iOS app I get:

```
    ld: framework not found package_info_plus
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried cleaning the project with `flutter clean` and building again after performing a pub get, but it doesn't solve the issue. I don't depend directly on package_info_plus, but there is one of my packages which does.
I've also tried adding package_info_plus to my pub spec, but then I get the same error again with the package path_provider, which I'm already using.

I have search and try every solution, but nothing works. Could somebody help me?

In case it helps, here you have my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: app name
description: App description

version: 2.0.0+12

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
  provider: ^6.0.0

  http: ^0.13.3
  device_info: ^2.0.2
  progress_state_button: ^1.0.3
  uuid: ^3.0.4
  universal_platform: ^1.0.0+1

  drift: ^1.0.0
  sqlcipher_flutter_libs: ^0.5.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.3
  path: ^1.8.0

  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.4
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0

  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4

  url_launcher: ^6.0.10

  flutter_slidable: ^1.1.0

  tuple: ^2.0.0

  get_it: ^7.2.0

  local_auth: ^1.1.7

  date_util: ^0.1.4

  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.3

  intl: ^0.17.0

  file_picker_cross: ^4.4.2
  share_extend: ^2.0.0

  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  drift_dev: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.0.4

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

And the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/javierd/Android/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (7 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/javierd/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/javierd/Downloads/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/javierd/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 8957D248-FB8E-4114-A3C1-E5DCF64FD39E • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)    • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.0.1
      21A559 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      96.0.4664.55

• No issues found!
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I'm having the same problem with a package

Comment: Nope. I Had to reinstall xcode completely to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

for me downgrade the package from the last version

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31547481)